# luajit ffi implementing a chunk finalizer

Tags: c, lua, libcurl, ffi, luajit

I'm working on wraping libcurl in luajit ffi. My finalizer isn't getting called.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef [[
  typedef struct{} CURL;
  CURL * curl_easy_init();
  void curl_easy_cleanup(CURL *);
]]

local CURL_lib = ffi.load("../lib/libcurl.so")
local CURL_CTX

local CURL_CTX_mt = {
  __gc = function()  print "finalizing"; CURL_lib.curl_easy_cleanup(CURL_CTX); end
}

ffi.metatype("CURL", CURL_CTX_mt)

CURL_CTX = ffi.new("CURL[1]")
CURL_CTX = CURL_lib.curl_easy_init();
print "done"
```

What am I missing here ? :D

BTW CURL is defined as `typedef void CURL;` I'm sure the way I am trying to do it isn't clean enough. Any advice ?

**eureka ! : self answer -- still interested in comments if there any glaring issues.**

Comment: if you discover an answer yourself, you should post it as an actual answer and accept it.

Comment: aah I thought one had to wait for a timeout before a self-answer can be done. Thanks. Aah you cannot accept your own answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

Compile time types in luajit must be `structs` (or `unions` I think) if you initialize your context type as a pointer, it is no longer a `struct`. So, there is a concept mismatch going on here. So, to fix things, add a `void *` to your `struct`, hang the `metatype` on the `struct`, and use the `void *` for the library context.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef [[
  typedef struct { void * ctx; } curl;
  curl * curl_easy_init();
  void curl_easy_cleanup(curl *);
]]

local curl_lib = ffi.load("../lib/libcurl.so")
local curl

local curl_mt = {
  __gc = function()  curl_lib.curl_easy_cleanup(curl.ctx); end
}

local curl_proto = ffi.metatype("curl", curl_mt)

curl = curl_proto(nil)
curl.ctx = curl_lib.curl_easy_init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or You can just register finalizer on returned pointer like this:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef [[
    typedef struct{} CURL;
    CURL * curl_easy_init();
    void curl_easy_cleanup(CURL *);
]]

local CURL_lib = ffi.load("../lib/libcurl.so")

local function curl_pointer_finalizer(pointer)
    print "finalizing"
    CURL_lib.curl_easy_cleanup(pointer)
end

local function curl_easy_init()
    return ffi.gc(CURL_lib.curl_easy_init(), curl_pointer_finalizer)
end

local CURL_CTX = curl_easy_init() -- wrapper func
print "done"
```